# Gnome 3 fallback mode after bumblebee install

Tags: fedora, gnome3, optimus

I followed [this guide to install bumblebee on Fedora 16](https://duxyng.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/finally-working-nvidia-optimus-on-fedora-16/), and I did everything in the tutorial.
Bumblebee seems to work as `optirun glxgears` returns non-vsynced frame rates, but Gnome 3 is in fallback mode.
`glxgears` or any other 3D application won't start, so I doubt it's Gnome specific.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the X server was trying to load the NVIDIA GLX module, and not the one for the Intel GPU.

All you have to do is add the following section to your `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Module"
    Load "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so"
EndSection
```

After a reboot Gnome won't start in fallback mode, and you can use both GPUs.